# when focusing html input text area in webview of android, i can not prevent software keyboard open

Tags: android, webview

In my application, i don't want use any built in software keyboard.
Instead of it i am using a gridlayout that i wrote.

I have a webview , and webview loads a html page that have inputs in it. Input types are text. On android emulator, when i click on any  input in webview, Android displays its softare keyboard. And i could not prevent this keyboard.

At c# i wrote the code below, but it does not work;

```
    void DisableSoftwareKeyPad(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        View vv = (View)sender;
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService("input_method");
        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(vv.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);



    }
```

I even tried on manifest file , it does not work too;

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

How can i do this?